# How to handle call to member function get() on non-object PHPunit Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am attempting to test a service class which extends a abstract class.

When trying to run my test for the service classes I get the error 'Call to a member function get() on a non-object in ...'.

The method I am testing:

```
 public function findOneHolidayById($holidayId)
{
    $holiday = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->getRepository('Common\Entity\HolidayEntity')
                ->findOneBy(array('id' => $holidayId));
    return $holiday;
}
```

The test that I am running:

```
 public function testFindOneHolidayById()
{
    $holidayId = 40;
    $holidayService = new \Common\Service\Holiday\HolidayService();
    $holidayService->findOneHolidayById($holidayId);
}
```

The error is due to this code in the tested method:

```
$holidays = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('Common\Entity\HolidayEntity')
            ->findAll();
```

I believe i need to mock the methods called from the abstract controller, or something along that line, but am unsure as to how to approach this.
Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Full stack message:

```
...............E.
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\module\Common\src\Common\Controller\AbstractController.php on line 40

Call Stack:
    0.0004     125872   1. {main}() C:\xampp\php\phpunit:0
    0.0089     361456   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46
    0.0089     364872   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
    1.4460    6229720   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
    1.6645    6549216   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:406
   36.0976   39708632   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:722
   39.3706   40551320   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:722
   39.3706   40551288   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:699
   39.3726   40554360   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestResult.php:609
   39.3758   40588552  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:743
   39.3759   40589080  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:866
   39.3759   40589200  12. CommonTest\Service\HolidayServiceTest->testFindOneHolidayById() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:866
   39.6060   41121200  13. Common\Service\Holiday\HolidayService->findOneHolidayById() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\module\Common\test\CommonTest\Service\HolidayServiceTest.php:34
   39.6060   41121200  14. Common\Controller\AbstractController->getEntityManager() C:\xampp\htdocs\Effcomm-SA-Portal-V1.0\effcomm-sa-portal\module\Common\src\Common\Service\Holiday\HolidayService.php:57
```

body of getEntityManager:

```
 protected function getEntityManager()
{
    if (is_null($this->entityManager)) {
        $this->entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()
                ->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    }
    return $this->entityManager;
}
```

Comment: Sharing the whole error message would be useful.

Comment: Are you certain that snippet is the offending code? I don't see an explicit call to a `get` function, so as @M.M. mentioned, some more stack trace would be useful.

Comment: I have added the stack to the question.

Comment: The reason I feel certain that that snippet is the offending code, is that if i comment it out the tests run. One of the methods accessed indirectly is get(), which is a private method used in another class.

Comment: Can you add body of getEntityManager() please?

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Call to a member function foobar() on a non-object` means that you're trying to call the `foobar()` method on a variable which is a not an object.

In your case, the problem is that you are calling `$this->getServiceLocator()` and expect it to return an instance of some service. However, it appears that `getServiceLocator` does't find the service you requested (in this case the EM), and I would guess that it returns `null` instead.

What you need to do is to check within the `getServiceLocator()` method if you got an object instance for the class you requested, and **throw an exception** if you can't load or create an instance.

Bonus points for writing a unit test which checks that the exception is properly thrown for non-existent services.